# Generate elevation profile graphs for multiple line segments in shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation, 3d-analyst, profile

I'm familiar with the profile graph feature in 3D analyst and I saw the stack profile tool as well.

However, I'd like to generate elevation profile graphs for 137 line segments.

I don't want to hand draw each segment, is there a tool to do this?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming the segments are independent lines? Sounds like a script/model that iterates through lines and runs the profile tool on each and specifying an output folder for the resulting profiles in the 3D Analyst options. What is the context? Are these profiles like trails, or cross sections along a waterway? There are some different custom tools out there aimed at different applications.

Comment: Any luck on this Whitney?  Looking to something very similar!